# Would this be considered trivia (as opposed to a puzzle), and if so, how should I flag it?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, close-reasons, specific-question

[This question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/34932/what-is-the-pseudonym-of-this-inventor) has kind of ruffled my feathers.  It simply lists out some factoids where everything is taken at face value, and does not attempt to hide or obscure the information.

I do not feel it belongs on the site, but the community may feel differently.  If I am "correct", how might I flag it? Nothing quite seems to fit my reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't feel the question fits with the site, you can flag it as "should be closed...", and then "off topic because...", and then "Other".  Leave a comment explaining why you think the question should be closed.

Once you have 3000 reputation, you can vote to close directly, selecting the same criteria.

Comment: "Other" is not an option for me. Under off-topic, I only get speculative, math, blatant, and migrate.  I thought I remembered seeing it before, but it's not there now.  I wonder if that's a result of my loss of privileges moving out of beta or some change in settings due to graduation?

Comment: @feelinferrety I can see "Other" there.  Maybe it only appears after a certain rep level?  Seems odd, if that's the case...

Comment: ಠ_ಠ That's just bizarre.

Comment: @feelinferrety I just voted to close this question.

Comment: And today I have discovered that the "migrate" option **only** comes with Meta PSE as selectable.

Comment: @feelinferrety I think meta PSE is the only option for everyone (except maybe mods). My understanding is that beta sites don't have migration paths, and once you're out of beta, you need to explicitly set them up, which I doubt we've done yet. But I'm no authority on the issue.